# BigInt vs boolean size PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have tables with columns containing indicators which can contain values 0 or 1 (0 denoting false, 1 denoting true). I would assume converting the type from number into boolean would lead to a size reduction in the written table. I did a little experiment writing two tables, both containing an identical ID column, and one containing numeric values and the other containing boolean values:

```
import random

random.seed(30)

n = 1000000
ids = [random.randint(0, n*10) for i in range(0, n)]
indicators = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(0, n)]
bools = [bool(indicator) for indicator in indicators]

data_indicators = zip(ids, indicators)
df_indicators = spark.createDataFrame(data_indicators, ["id", "indicator"])

data_bools = zip(ids, bools)
df_bools = spark.createDataFrame(data_bools, ["id", "bool"])
```

However, both written tables (delta format) show to be 5.1MiB in size (the number type is transformed into BigInt). How is this possible?

I expected the table with the boolean type to be smaller

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom best to look at what the `createDataFrame` is doing: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/session.html#SparkSession.createDataFrame

Comment: From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html) createDataFrame second parameter (`schema`) is very flexible, we can pass different structures... When ``schema`` is a list of column names, the type of each column will be inferred from ``data`` ... maybe the inferred step is doing something unexpected, but you also have another option: `pyspark.sql.types.DataType` there is even an example there in the documentation ... You can try that to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference since the type in the resulting tables is already as expected (BigInt vs Boolean).

Comment: Maybe the size of the tables is determined by the contents not the column type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One optimization technique in [parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/), among many others, is bit-packing. If you have `BIGINT` column that has small numbers you only need to store the N significant bits that cover the range, for [0 - 1] range you only need 1 bit. See this [presentation](https://youtu.be/1j8SdS7s_NY?t=986).

Comment: I did another test, with the indicator values being between 0 or 10000 (instead of 0 to 1). This indeed resulted in a larger size for the table (in comparison to the boolean one). Does this mean we can assume that when writing delta tables in PySpark the parquet optimization technique is used?

Comment: [parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) Is a file format, [Delta](https://delta.io/) is a table format that provides a transaction log on top of the parquet files. So yes, when you write a Delta table the underlying files will be in parquet format.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing to see if Python uses a similar optimization technique for the variables and it seems that is indeed the case, `indicators` and `bools` are the same size, you can run the script below:

```py
from sys import getsizeof
import random

random.seed(30)

n = 1000000
ids = [random.randint(0, n*10) for i in range(0, n)]
indicators = [random.randint(0, n) for i in range(0, n)]
bools = [bool(indicator) for indicator in indicators]

print(getsizeof(indicators))
print(getsizeof(bools))
```

We get the same output from the prints `8448728`

---

Similar test in Javascript

```js
n = 1000000

ids = Array(n).fill().map(() => Math.random() * n*10)
indicators = Array(n).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random()))
bools = indicators.map((x) => Boolean(x))

class Foo {
    constructor(ids, indicators, bools) {
        this.ids = ids
        this.indicators = indicators
        this.bools = bools
    }
}

foo = new Foo(ids, indicators, bools)
alert("pause")
```

We can see in the heap profiler that `indicators` and `bools` have the same size

[image]